# WebAPI routing with / in

Tags: c#, webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

On my WebAPI .Net Framework 4.8

I have a WebAPI method with this route :

```
[Route("gdoc/a/G1/{code}/{path}/child")]
```

This route doesn't fully work because {path} value contains caracters "/" (it's a folder path)

How can I retrieve {path} value (in **bold**) for all these situations :

- https:/server/gdoc/a/G1/IDS/**5-787/folder1/james/titi.png**/child
- https:/server/gdoc/a/G1/IDS/**5-787/folder1/folder2/james/tata.png**/child
- https:/server/gdoc/a/G1/IDS/**5-787/folder1/folder2/folder3/jake/titi.png**/child

If it's not possible, have you another idea ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Change `{path}` to `{**path}` to make it a wildcard route parameter.

Comment: Doesn't work with {**path} but works with {*path} !

Thanks !